# Bypassing form based authentication for certain links in jsf

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am learning jsf.I have created a sample application which I have protected
using form based authentication.

I am able to login successfully using the correct passowrd.
The problem is that I have a register new user link on the login page. When I click on this link still the system asks for password.

I want to bypass authentication for the register link. How I can achieve that?